# Github API post works locally, but gets a 401 in a remote server

Tags: javascript, github-api

Hi I use the github API to send a file to a repo, I tested in postman in local and is working but when I deploy to my server it always return a 401 status, so I need t create another token, but when I deploy again ,I got the same error:
Any one has a solution for this?
I read here, and don't find anything useful:
https://docs.github.com/en/rest/overview/troubleshooting-the-rest-api?apiVersion=2022-11-28

here is the call and working in postman:

curl --location --request PUT 'https://api.github.com/repos/MY_ACCoUNT/JavaAsyncGraphql/contents/player/src/main/resources/example2.md' 
--header 'Authorization: Bearer mytoken' 
--header 'Accept: application/vnd.github+json' 
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' 
--data-raw '{
"message": " tets api file",
"content": "LS0tCnRpdGxlOiAiV3JpdGUgYSBoaWdoIENUUiBtZXRhIGRlc2NyaXB0aW9uICYgdGl0bGUiCmRhdGU6ICIyMDIzLTA3LTA4VDIzOjExOjM4Ljg1MVoiCnRodW1iOiAiV3JpdGVfYV9oaWdoX0NUUl9tZXRhX2Rlc2NyaXB0aW9uXyZfdGl0bGUucG5nIgp0YWdzOiBbQ29udGVudCwgU0VPLCBNYXJrZXRpbmcsIE90aGVyc10KLS0tCgojIFdyaXRlIGEgaGlnaCBDVFIgbWV0YSBkZXNjcmlwdGlvbiAmIHRpdGxlCgpbTGlua10oaHR0cHM6Ly90d2l0dGVyLmNvbS9oZXlsb3Zpc2gvc3RhdHVzLzE2MzgxNjQ0MDM2NTU2OTYzODQpCioqRHVlIHRvIG5ldyB0d2l0dGVyIHBvbGljeSB5b3UgbmVlZCB0byBsb2dpbiB0byB2aXN1YWxpemUgdGhlIHRocmVhZCoqCg=="
}'

in my program:

```
var markdown_encode = btoa(markdown);
 var headers = { 
'Authorization': 'Bearer mytoken',
'Accept': 'application/vnd.github+json'
  }



  var body = {
        "message": "adding " + filename,
        "content": markdown_encode
    }
    const url = `${url_base}${repoName}/contents/${pathFile}/${filename}.md`;

fetch(url, {
    method: 'PUT',
    headers,
    body: JSON.stringify(body)
  })
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
        const sha = data.content.sha;
        console.log(sha);
        alert("success ith a sha " + sha);
        
        })
  .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
        alert(JSON.stringify(error.message))
  });
```

the result after trying from deploy:
[image]
Regards

Comment: Well, are you absolutely sure you're sending the correct token from your deployed code too?

Comment: yeah, not sure what is the issue, is like always expire it when I deploy to the server and call the end-point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was when you commit the token of the github-api in a repo, because Github scan your repos and when it find a token github will expired it for security reasons.

Comment: This feature of automatically expiring security tokens that get committed to a repo is [documented on GitHub](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/token-expiration-and-revocation#token-revoked-when-pushed-to-a-public-repository-or-public-gist)